# How can I implement a/b split testing the easiest way in Drupal 7?

Tags: testing, split, drupal-7

Drupal has a few split testing modules but I can't find one that compatible with recently released (as of this writing) Drupal 7. I could try to use Google Website Optimizer but, I'm new to Drupal, and not sure how I could edit the Head HTML to insert the unique JavaScripts on each page (I assume they all share the same Head declarations).

Can someone help?

Comment: I am new to Drupal, laugh away. I know what the page.tpl (where the HEAD info is) is but my understanding is that this is shared across every page and I want to know, as a Drupal beginner, if it's possible to update the HEAD info on each individual page with different JavaScript code (or ideally with a 7.x compatible module)...as my question clearly indicated above. And after toiling around in the Drupal 7 admin interface, as well as asking questions to no avail in #drupal, I have come here, where, people like you should try to help rather than ridicule. Congrats you've earned the 'rude' badge

Comment: And you obviously have no clue how to achieve this. Shouldn't you be commenting on YouTube?

Answer (score 3):

There's already [a dedicated Drupal module](http://drupal.org/project/google_website_optimizer) for inserting the GWO code into pages where it's appropriate. If you need to do something more exotic, use it as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

FYI for others who stumble on this, the Google Website Optimizer module linked by Eaton is now unsupported and obsolete.

With a quick search I found the Multivariate module at https://www.drupal.org/project/multivariate that can be used to setup multivariate or A/B tests.